# How to filter according to a cell value using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two sheets in a workbook. I am using the following VBA code to filter the data:

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160623
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.Range("A4").AutoFilter 1, "=001"
    Next
End Sub
```

Now I want to use the value in cell F1 in place of 001. How do I modify the code?

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/774984/peterh   PeterH can you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy mate, try:

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()

    ' Updateby Extendoffice 20160623

    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.Range("A4").AutoFilter FIELD:=1, CRITERIA1:=xWs.range("F1").value
    Next
End Sub
```

cheers

Comment: Thank you. But I have many worksheet in same workbook and I want to change at a time. Can you help me out.

Comment: @Suyash You want to pick a sheet in specific? Because you are looping all the sheets on this workbook.

Comment: It is not working with other sheet Can you help me.